# Vertical scrolling is not stopping correctly in Mobile and Desktop

Tags: mobile

I made my first website using wordpress and elementor, but its scrolling is not working properly. The website is https://www.pianoalemdasteclas.com.br

When you scroll down or up, the page does not stop right in the moment. It always throws the page a bit up or a bit down. In mobile you can see it more clearly.

I only used one speed plugin on the website and all the other elements are native from wordpress or elementor.

Any ideias about what I should do to solve it? Thanks.